# Return the string value of what is selected in the drop down list

Tags: python, html, django

I have a list of stops:

```
<select name="dropdown">
    {% for stop in stop_list %}
        <option value ="{{ stop.name }}">{{ stop.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

and a Stops model where one of the attributes is name.

I also have a method find_direction() in my views.py that requires a stop.location input.

How do I record the value of the selected stop.name so I can then get the stop.location to use in views.py?

Thanks!

Currently my method is:

```
def find_direction(request, stop1name, stop2name):
    stop1 = get_object_or_404(Stops, name=stop1name)
    stop2 = get_object_or_404(Stops, name=stop2name)
```

which gives the error: find_direction() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'stop1' and 'stop2name'.. How do I make it record these two variables correctly from the selected drop down list?

Using forms but for some reason..

```
print(request.GET.get("stop1id", "default_value"))
print(request.GET.get("stop2id", "default_value"))
print(request.method)
print(request.POST.dict())
print(request.GET.dict())
print(request.body)
```

all return empty

Comment: You need to send the value back to your server via an HTTP request.  Once the template is created and sent off to the client.  That data would need to be communicated back to the server somehow.  What are you trying to do with the value?  The answer to that question would determine what I would suggest from there.

Comment: The value is a name. So I would look to get the corresponding Stop and then from there get the Stop location. Thanks, I appreciate the answer.

Comment: Are the stop locations stored on the client side?

Comment: They're stored on the server I believe. I've updated the main post to show what I'm currently doing, maybe that will help determine the best fix.

Answer (score 0):

In light of your update, you will most like want to pass the data in a request:

```
def find_direction(request):
    stop1 = get_object_or_404(Stops, name=request.POST.get("stop1name","default_value"))
    stop2 = get_object_or_404(Stops, name=request.POST.get("stop2name","default_value"))
```

This assumes you are sending a `POST` request from a form back to the server with the stop name data.  The dictionary keys `stop1name` and `stop2name` should match the names as they are set in your form:

```
<form action="/get_stop_locations">
     <select name="stop1name">
        {% for stop in stop_list %}
        <option value ="{{ stop.name }}">{{ stop.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
     </select>
     <select name="stop2name">
        {% for stop in stop_list %}
        <option value ="{{ stop.name }}">{{ stop.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
     </select>
</form>
```

If you are curious, you were receiving an error because positional arguments for django views are set up as captured bits of a url:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django_app.views',
    url(r'^get_stop_locations/(\w+)/(\w+)$','positional_get_locations'),
)
```

**views.py**

```
def positional_get_locations(request,stop1name,stop2name):
    stop1 = get_object_or_404(Stops, name=stop1name)
    stop2 = get_object_or_404(Stops, name=stop2name)
```

Django views requires one argument by default which will store the request object.  When there are more views defined, the view expects more arguments to be provided by the url handler.  If the url is not set up to pull as many arguments as possible in your **urls.py** file, you will see this error.

For your case, this requires setting up some tricky URLs however on the client side and I wouldn't recommend it.  See this [example in the DJango Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#example) for more information on positional arguments in Django views.

**EDIT**:

In response to your `MultiValueDictKeyError`, try:

```
def find_direction(request):
    stop1 = get_object_or_404(Stops, name=request.POST.get("stop1name","default_value"))
    stop2 = get_object_or_404(Stops, name=request.POST.get("stop2name","default_value"))
```

Comment: I see! Thanks for your help. I tried your method and it seems to be working but raises a MultiValueDictKeyError. I'm assuming that's exactly what it sounds like and such a "name" appears multiple times?

Comment: I've swapped it for an ID key which is unique and I am still getting a MultiValueDictKeyError. Is there anything other than multiple keys found that could be causing this?

Comment: @tryingtolearn hmmm, no it means that the variable you are looking for does not exist in the `MultiValueDict`.  See my edit.  If that does not fix it, could you provide more of the template context showing your form, or however you are posting to the server?

Comment: I'm receiving No Stops matches the given query. when I insert that. If I'm able to select it from the drop down isn't that proof that it should exist in the database? I've updated the original post to display what I've got exactly.

Comment: @tryingtolearn I would suggest you try and print out what is being passed `print request.POST.get("stop1id","default_value")`.  If it is `"default_value"`, then the error is somewhere in how the data is being passed.  If not, you can see the value that is being searched for in your database. This will further our diagnosis.

Comment: @tryingtolearn you should put it as the first line in your view.

Comment: Ah yes, it returns "default_value".

Comment: Do I need to include the urls.py script you wrote?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74669/discussion-between-farmer-joe-and-tryingtolearn).

Comment: Hi Joe, I was wondering if perhaps the difficulty was in the URL
Currently it is, 

url(r'^app/$', login_required(journeyPlan), name="journey_planner"), 
url(r'^app/route/$', route, name="route"),
The selection from the drop down list takes place at /app/. So I'm trying to select it there and then pass it to /app/route/ where it can be used to find_distance. Is there something not being passed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your dropdown located in a form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="">   
      <select name="dropdown">
      {% for stop in stop_list %}
      <option value ="{{ stop.name }}">{{ stop.name }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
      </select>
     <input type="submit" />   
</form>
```

You can `get` the value by defining the following in your views:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):                                    
    if 'dropdown' in request.POST:               
        dropdown_val = request.POST.get('dropdown', False)
```

Comment: I tried using this method and I received this error: local variable 'dropdown_val' referenced before assignment. Any idea what might be going wrong?